# How would I represent a 1D array into a 2D in the case of the 8 Queens Puzzle

Tags: java, arrays

So I have this basic N Queen Program solver.

It is made so that it gives all the possible solutions in 1 Array. In other words, if I get an array with values : {5,3,2,1,7,8,5,3}, it would mean that the first index represent the row and the value of that index its column.

My issue with this program is that I have tried to "graphically" represent a chessboard with the solution of that array on it. The method "printTable" is supposed to convert that 1D array into a 2D array following the rules I have explained. I then tried to to implement that method into the QueenSolve method. This is where it gets nasty.

I have tried the printTable method and it works perfectly on its own, however when I use it with the QueenSolve method, It doesn't give me the expected result.

I must have done something wrong with the array. If you compile this code below, you will see that the first solution to the 8 Queens puzzle is fine, however as you go along, you will see that some Queens start to go on top of each other, and in the end it is really messy.

I was just wondering if there was a solution to my problem. I understand that there must be an issue revolving around the result array. I tried to find some ways of dealing with that by storing the result array (aka one solution) with an array list and then go one from there, however I would get some different results.

If anyone could just have a look through this program and have it compile. I would appreciate any sort of help. 
Thanks!

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NQueens {
    static int[] result; 
    private int board[][]=new int[8][8];
    private int N =8;
    private int u=0;

public boolean QueenChecker(int x, int y) {

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {

        if ((result[i] == y) || (Math.abs(i - x) == Math.abs(result[i] - y))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public void QueenSolve(int x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (QueenChecker(x, i)) {
            result[x] = i; // place the queen at this position.
            if (x == result.length - 1) {

                printTable(result,N);
            }
            QueenSolve(x + 1);
        }
    }
}

public void printTable(int result[], int N)
{
    for(int s=0;s<result.length;s++){
        for (int u=0;u<result.length;u++)
        {
            board[s][result[s]]=1;
        }  

        for(int j=0;j<result.length;j++){

            if(board[s][j]==1)
                System.out.print("Q");
            else
                System.out.print("*" );
        }

        System.out.println();//"\n");
    }
}

public void AllSolutions(int j)
{
    System.out.println("Solution : "+ j);
    printTable(result,N);
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 8;
    result = new int[n];

    NQueens i = new NQueens();
    i.QueenSolve(0);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you use some paragraphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem you have is that you are never clearing your board.

A quick 'n dirty solution to your problem is to make sure at the beginning of your print method that you get a "fresh" board.

```
public void printTable(int result[], int N)
{
    // Clear the board.
    board = new int[8][8];

    for(int s=0;s<result.length;s++){
        for (int u=0;u<result.length;u++)
        {
            board[s][result[s]]=1;
        }  

        for(int j=0;j<result.length;j++){

            if(board[s][j]==1)
                System.out.print("Q");
            else
                System.out.print("*" );
        }

        System.out.println();//"\n");
    }

    // Line at the end to separate the different boards from one another.
    System.out.println("---------------------");
}
```

This is just an obvious problem I spotted right away. There might be more - I didn't check thoroughly. And the solution I'm offering is not best practice but rather just a quick 'n dirty one. Once you have it working as you expect, I suggest you head over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to ask how you can improve your code.

Comment: Thank you! I added a method that clears the board after each printing of my  2D array. Works just fine !